# redownload param for AdSet does not work

Tags: python-3.x, facebook-ads-api

I am trying to use redownload to download all fields of an AdSet but it doesn't seem to be working. 
Here is my code:

```
ad_set = AdSet('6049562095738')
response=ad_set.api_get(params={AdSet.Field.redownload:True})
print(response)
```

and I get

> { "id": "6049562095738" }

Comment: Please, add programming language tag. What is it? Python?

Comment: added Python as a Tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a GET request - the redownload param is on the POST path and returns some of the fields of the newly created or updated object

You should specify which fields you want via the `fields` parameter when reading ads

Comment: Thanks Igy. Is redownload param available only for POST requests ? I want to download all the fields and not any specific fields. I want to make my program forward compatible, in the sense that if new fields are added in future versions of the API, then program need not be changed.

Comment: No, for GET requests you should request just the fields your app needs (i.e those that your business logic, reporting, etc uses); fetching all fields wouldn't add any value to your app, and you'd still need to change it for each new version of the API anyway to account for the backwards-incompatible changes - you'd also unnecessarily encounter slower API responses and be affected by field-specific bugs in fields you don't need, etc

Comment: Do you mind pointing me to the section in Facebook Documentation where it says that its meant only for GET requests

Comment: It's only for POST requests, it's listed in the creation and editing sections of the relevant objects' documentation - e.g. 'Ad' here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/adgroup